# Why can't I log in to my Samba share on my home network?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba

Recently I've had to reinstall Ubuntu Server 15.10 64-bit after wiping my home server due to an insecure password-only SSH server sitting on it for too long. Now, I'm plagued with setting my machine up again and along with it is Samba shares. I'm able to get Samba to correctly share a folder publicly, but I'm currently looking to make only 1 private share available that can only be signed in from the one main user on the machine.

Testparm gives no errors. [Here is my `smb.conf` file.](https://paste.ubuntu.com/14990989/)

I've made sure that:

1. My user account is a part of the `sambashare` group.
2. I have `sudo smbpasswd -a <user>` and `sudo smbpasswd -e <user>` for my username on the machine.
3. My username has permission to read and write folders and files on the folder the share is pointed to.

To make sure there are no errors, I've increased the log level in `smb.conf` and [here is the output of an average `sudo service smbd restart` on `/var/log/samba/log.smbd`.](https://paste.ubuntu.com/14990995/)

Whenever I go to my Windows machines and go to my server's SMB shares, I see the share "storage" appear. Clicking on it makes it load for a tiny second and then it asks for authentication because access was denied. Then, I type in my server's username & password I set up with `smbpasswd` and it still says access is denied. What am I missing?

**Note:** I've installed samba previously on this machine and then immediately purged it after this failure occured. Later, I reinstalled samba and I noted some things were astray. I corrected them and I'm back to this issue again.

Comment: I wrote an answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/724875/231142) that I tested and it worked.   Maybe it might help you.  I never heard a response from the person asking the question.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks for the suggestion but those did not work.

Comment: @Terrance Think you can upload a copy of your smb.conf? Maybe I'll see what's different.

Comment: Sure, [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/14991321/) you go.  I did notice some `ntlmv` and `ntlm` that I have on my smb.conf that I didn't see in yours.  None of my shares though are set for user level at the moment.

Comment: I don't think it's that, I don't have ntlmv/ntlm in my setup and it's working fine here (both Windows and smbclient directly)

Comment: @Terrance I notice you don't have any private shares on your server. All your shares appear to be publicly available to guests. I am trying to host a share that is only accessible to one user.

Comment: @dylanweber Here are images of how mine is working.  [First](http://i.imgur.com/AA46hiT.jpg) showing denied.  [Second](http://i.imgur.com/wceo104.jpg) putting in username and password.  [Third](http://i.imgur.com/tvZDBwP.jpg) access granted.  Hoping we can get to the bottom of why your's isn't working.

Comment: @dylanweber I changed the Whipple one to `guest ok = no` and `valid users = terrance`

Comment: I have a feeling that the root of my issue has to do with the sambashare group.

Comment: I just took your config (@dylanweber), changed only the username to my own and the path to my regular share and I was able to connect with smbclient.  So, I think you can rule out the config file as the source of the problem.

Comment: @dylanweber One quick question, you are restarting the `smbd` in between setting changes, right?  `sudo service smdb restart`

Comment: Yes definitely. Sometimes rebooting, even. Hopefully rebooting isn't too much.

Comment: @dylanweber OK, just checking.  =)

Comment: Really appreciate your help, I've been at this for over 24 hours and I cannot figure this out.

Comment: @dylanweber Have you tried your normal login password instead of the smbpasswd you set?

Comment: They're both the same. `smbpasswd` is set to sync passwords, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35435/discussion-between-terrance-and-dylanweber).

Comment: Have you tried `write list = dylanweber` instead of `valid user =`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion that I have reached is that I couldn't connect to my share because the version of Samba that is installed with Ubuntu 15.10 (Samba 4.1.17) had a bug that didn't allow it to properly authenticate users. My solution for this problem was installing Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and using Samba 4.1.6 along with it. Now Samba works flawlessly.

**Note**: I retried with a fresh copy of Ubuntu Server 15.10 to validate my conclusion and it is clear that Samba 4.1.17 in Ubuntu Server 15.10 is buggy.

My recommended solution? Install Debian instead.

Answer (score 1):

The CUPS errors are not an issue.  I get those also with my setup and I have no trouble accessing samba shares.

Is your firewall turned on and if so, is samba being blocked?

Is the dylanweber user also a regular login id on your system?  Have you tried using your regular login password (if different from what you set for samba)?

If you try to access the share directly from the linux box, does that work?  i.e. something like:

```
> smbclient //1.2.3.4/storage
```

from a prompt in the 1.2.3.4 host itself logged in as dylanweber

Comment: Sadly, no. https://paste.ubuntu.com/14991225/ Additionally, my regular login password is the same as my Samba password. I don't know if Samba is being blocked by a firewall, but considering the fact that it's not working locally probably suggests something else is wrong.

Comment: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED sounds to me like you might not have access to that path as dylanweber in the filesystem.  For instance, is the storage folder owned by root and not read/exe by anyone else?

Comment: When I SSH as dylanweber, I can touch files and edit files without sudo. I have read and write permissions on that directory.

Comment: long-shot question but is /media/storage some sort of fuse filesystem?  such as encfs

Comment: Nope. It's a regular ext4 filesystem on a separate LVG partition mounted at /media/storage/ on boot.